# Selecting element with JS issue

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand this. I have HTML code like this:

```
<div id="one">
  <div>
    <div>
       <span class="spanone"></span>
       <span class="spantwo"></span>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
.
.(some other html of the page)
.
<sometag class="spanone"></sometag>
<someothertag class="spantwo"></someothertag>
```

And I basically want to target **only** the first `<span>` and the second by JS without touching the `sometags` elements. In other words the: `<span class="spanone">` and `<span class="spantwo">`. And then I want to use `innerHTML` to replace the code with the one I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code? Do you use jquery?

Comment: Hi @franenos, can you post what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var spanone = document.querySelector('.span1');
var spantwo = document.querySelecftor('.span2');

spanone.innerHTML = "Replacement";
spantwo.innerHTML = "Replacement";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a couple ways

Use `id`

```
<span class="spanone" id="myspan1"></span>
<span class="spantwo" id="myspan2"></span>
```

so in vanilla JS

```
var d = document;

d.getElementById('myspan1');
d.getElementById('myspan2');
```

or with classes

```
<span class="spanone myspans"></span>
<span class="spantwo myspans"></span>
```

and in your JS

```
d.querySelectorAll('.myspans')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 var spanone = document.querySelector('.spanone')[0];
 var spantwo = document.querySelecftor('.spantwo')[0];
```